# Importing project and migrating to Gradle: Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm importing a project that may have been created in Eclipse to Android Studio. I'm not quite sure how to migrate to Gradle and the official docs aren't much of a help. The structure is as follows:

```
> app-android
    > app
    > swipelist_lib
    > coollib_2
    > another lib
    > ...
```

The project has no build.gradle files so I added one in app-android and app. Then followed Studio to add a Gradle home. What exactly do I add in these files? Should I be adding the libraries manually by going through Project Structure > Dependencies or through the build.gradle file?

I'm currently getting `Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.` and my project only has app folder showing (I'm assuming it should have the same structure as above)

My current app build.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 8
      targetSdkVersion 19
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
    }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":lib")
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.1'
   compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

The app-android build.grade file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1’
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `2.2.1` to `1.1.0`, which is the latest current version of the Gradle for Android plugin. 2.2.1 is the version of *Gradle*, which goes in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, in the `distributionUrl`, if you have those.

> Should I be adding the libraries manually by going through Project Structure > Dependencies or through the build.gradle file?

Either way works. Personally, I work with the `build.gradle` files directly.

Comment: @ono: Then compare your build files against ones that are known to work. For example, you could use the Android Studio new-project wizard to create a scrap project for comparison purposes.

Comment: So the key is in the build.gradle files? I technically don't need to add anything else? should I have two of them as I described above?

Comment: @ono: "So the key is in the build.gradle files?" -- yes, for that error and for your question on dependencies. "I technically don't need to add anything else?" -- you need a `settings.gradle` file, in the project root, listing the modules (app modules and library modules). That should not be contributing to your error, though. "should I have two of them as I described above?" -- you should have one per module plus one in the top level (in the project root). Again, I suggest that you create a scrap Android Studio project to use as a comparison point.

Comment: Ended up removing the project then re-importing it Android Studio recognized it as an Eclipse project and created the build.gradle files for me. What luck.